# ASP.net MVC Url.Action Link formatting

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, url.action

I'm very new to ASP.net and recently converting from asp.net to asp.net MVC projects. 
I have one basic question in asp.net MVC Url.Action.

I have one `ActionResult` method with two parameters `QuestionId, Response` in my controller, and routing configuration as follows,

```
public class QuestionController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Answer(int QuestionId, string Response)
    {
       ..do something.....
    }
}
```

and routing configuration mapped as

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "QuestionAnswer",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{QuestionId}/{Response}",
                defaults: new { controller ="Question", action = "Answer", QuestionId = 0, Response = string.Empty}
            );
```

Calling the action Link in html page from the below syntax

```
@Html.ActionLink("Answer is 1", "Answer", "Question", null, null, null, new RouteValueDictionary(new {QuestionId = 10, Response = "1" }), null)
```

it forming URL Like /Question/Answer?QuestionID=10&Response=1, this url match the routing defintion and calls the Action properly. Everything is fine.

But my actual requirement is these parameter names should not be exposed. It should be like
/Question/Answer/10/1

I don't want to manually format this link with the help of `String.Format` since my site may placed inside a virtual directory not as default web site.

Comment: you can try this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/576514/AplusBeginner-splusTutorialplusonplusVariousplus

Answer (score 0):

Because the ActionLink will perform a GET request the values will always be in the query string. One way to remove the questionId and response from the querystring is to perform a POST to your answer action with the questionId and the response parameters using a form.

Other options are to perform a ajax request and update the dom on the response.